# How to setup spring boot api with postgress working on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, jdbc

I created Postgress + Spring app and It works perfectly locally (I had different docker-compose file fot it, but it works)

The target is: I want to deploy it to GCP.

I'm already running Postgress DB on GCP.
Done more or less with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@avabhyankar22/deploying-a-spring-boot-app-as-a-docker-image-on-gcp-using-kubernetes-d2de68fe3dda)

And tbh for me it looks good:

Now I want also put my api onto the GCP that will be using this DB
But firstly I need to test it locally.
I'm running my app with docker:
[image]

And when I try to run it connection fails:
[image]

What am I missing?

It's my first time deploying DB + API onto GCP, so I'm kinda doing it blindly
So any reamrks will be apprecieated :D

Sorry for so little information, but I honestly don't know what more info I can give You :/

(I do not care wheter it is done perfectly or not)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please be careful as you just shared the information of your db's public IP and some credentials.

Comment: Yeah I don’t care about this db as it was already deleted :)
Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a PostgreSQL instance on Cloud SQL I'd recommend that you read over [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview) because there are multiple ways of doing it.

Basically the connection requires:

- Having a client to connect from.
- Configuring the db to accept connections and allow the client's requests. This includes not only granting a public IP but also whitelisting the given client's source IP address/range.
- Performing the connection itself.

In your particular case, my recommendation would be that you run locally a Cloud SQL Auth Proxy container along your application. It allows you to perform the connections by simply using the connection name and the credentials of a Service Account with client access (at least `roles/cloudsql.client`). Using this proxy also eliminates the need of manually whitelisting your source IP.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  cloudsql-proxy:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.7.2
    command: ${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME} --credentials-file=/credentials.json --address 0.0.0.0 --port 5432
    volumes:
    - ./sqlproxy_key.json:/credentials.json
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
  app:
    [...]
    depends_on:
    - cloudsql-proxy
```

It will also allow you to perform connections from both your local computer and whichever GCP service you choose rather similarly (depending on the service). As a best practice, the idea would be to connect to one host or another according to the environment variables read from your application.

I'd recommend that you go through [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-auth-proxy#docker) to understand how the connection is configured with the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy, and [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#java) to see how it's done from Cloud Run (as an example).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check this [link](https://dev.to/tienbku/docker-compose-spring-boot-and-postgres-example-4l82) wherein in it uses JSON environment file.

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:$POSTGRESDB_DOCKER_PORT/$POSTGRESDB_DATABASE",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$POSTGRESDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```